# How to force var4 in registers.

Tags: cuda

I have the following representative code:

```
__global__ void func()
{
    register ushort4 result = make_ushort4(__float2half_rn(0.5), __float2half_rn(0.5), __float2half_rn(0.5), __float2half_rn(1.0));
}
```

When compiling, `result` is stored in local memory. Is it possible to force this to registers? Local memory is too slow for the intended application.

Furthermore, this result must be stored to an array of var4 elements. I would like to store these results coalesced, like `((ushort4*)(output))[x + y * width] = result;`. Another solution without var4 is also an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector type should be compiled into registers *if* there is available registers to do so. Turning your snippet into something that will survive dead code removal:

```
__global__ void func(ushort4 *out) 
{ 
    ushort4 result = make_ushort4(__float2half_rn(0.5), __float2half_rn(0.5), 
            __float2half_rn(0.5), __float2half_rn(1.0)); 

    out[threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x] = result;
}
```

and compiling it:

```
>nvcc -cubin -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" ushort4.cu
ushort4.cu
ushort4.cu
tmpxft_000010b8_00000000-3_ushort4.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_000010b8_00000000-10_ushort4.cudafe2.gpu
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z4funcP7ushort4' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z4funcP7ushort4
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 36 bytes cmem[0]
```

shows no spills (ie. local memory). Further, disassembling the resulting cubin file shows:

```
>cuobjdump --dump-sass ushort4.cubin

        code for sm_20
                Function : _Z4funcP7ushort4
        /*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
        /*0008*/     /*0x01101c041000cfc0*/     F2F.F16.F32 R0, 0x3f000;
        /*0010*/     /*0x94009c042c000000*/     S2R R2, SR_CTAid_X;
        /*0018*/     /*0x8400dc042c000000*/     S2R R3, SR_Tid_X;
        /*0020*/     /*0x01111c041000cfe0*/     F2F.F16.F32 R4, 0x3f800;
        /*0028*/     /*0x00915c041c000000*/     I2I.U16.U16 R5, R0;
        /*0030*/     /*0x20209c0320064000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 R2, R2, c [0x0] [0x8], R3;
        /*0038*/     /*0x40019c03280ac040*/     BFI R6, R0, 0x1010, R5;
        /*0040*/     /*0x4041dc03280ac040*/     BFI R7, R4, 0x1010, R5;
        /*0048*/     /*0x80201c6340004000*/     ISCADD R0, R2, c [0x0] [0x20], 0x3;
        /*0050*/     /*0x00019ca590000000*/     ST.64 [R0], R6;
        /*0058*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
                .................................
```

ie. the `ushort4` is stuffed into register and then a 64 bit store is used to write the packed vector out to global memory. No local memory access to be seen.

So if you have convinced yourself that you have a vector value compiling into local memory, it is either because you have a kernel with a lot of register pressure, or you are asking the compiler to (the `volatile` keyword will do that), or you have misinterpreted what the compiler/assembler are telling you at compile time.

---

EDIT: Using the CUDA 4.0 release tookit with Visual Studio Express 2008 and compiling on 32bit Windows 7 for a compute 1.1 device gives:

```
>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_May_13_02:42:40_PDT_2011
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.0, V0.2.1221

>cl.exe
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]


>nvcc -cubin -arch=sm_11 -Xptxas=-v ushort4.cu
ushort4.cu
ushort4.cu
tmpxft_00001788_00000000-3_ushort4.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_00001788_00000000-10_ushort4.cudafe2.gpu
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z4funcP7ushort4' for 'sm_11'
ptxas info    : Used 4 registers, 4+16 bytes smem
```

which is the exact same result as for the original build for a compute 2.0 target.

Comment: This is the result for your suggested function: `2>ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z4funcP7ushort4' for 'sm_11'
2>ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 32+0 bytes lmem, 16+16 bytes smem, 4 bytes cmem[1]`. Furthermore, I am bound to sm11.

Comment: @Patrik: what compiler version and operating system is this? I have compiled this with both Cuda 3.2 and 4.0 for sm11, sm12 and sm20. All emit code using only registers.

Comment: I use VS2008 and cmake; nvcc release 4.0, V0.2.1221; options=--gpu-architecture=sm_11 --ptxas-options=-v; os = vista;

Comment: @Patrik: I am sorry, but I cannot reproduce that. See the edit.

Comment: @talonmier Thanks for your help, I'll do some more testing on another computer. At least now I know it should work.